# How to exterminate/identify these insects?

Tags: pest-control, bedroom, insect

A week ago, insect bite marks started showing up on my arms, and I couldn't sleep in my bed. I tried to find the culprit but was unsuccessful. Today I opened up my lamp cover and found these:

[image: insect category 1]

[image: insect category 2]

I think I still have a these insects in my room but my body has adjusted, so I'm not irritated as much now.

Can someone please help me identify these things and help me get rid of them ? I can post higher resolution pictures if you need.

More pictures : [image: category 1]

[image: category 2]

Comment: Identifying insects might be off-topic here. Anyway I think you'd need higher-resolution photos **with some indication of scale** such as a ruler in the photo. Putting up insect screens on the windows would be on-topic, hanging a mosquito-net from the ceiling also?

Comment: When Identifying bugs, nothing beats having feet on the ground.  Save a sample and call a local exterminator.  The exterminators in my area will inspect for free.

Comment: [Biology.SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23887/can-anyone-identify-this-bug) doesn't seem adverse to identifying bugs. Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

They are some kind midge flies (chironomids (*Chironomidae*))... obviously a biting kind of midge fly. A species specific identification would require a much better image, or preferably- a sample of the actual insects.

I see that you live in India... that makes identification more difficult because entomology is not a thoroughly studied science there.

Generally speaking, midge flies are controlled in the larval state (before they become adult flies). They are a lot like mosquitoes; they lay eggs in stagnant water (sewage, ponds, and drains are common). The larvae are commonly called redworms.

[image]

Eliminating the (stagnant water) source of the midge flies would be the most effective control, of course. Otherwise, a natural control method (recommended) would be *Bacillus thuringiensis* subspecies *israelensis* which can be found in many box-stores... look for "mosquito dunks".